# [ImageJ Macro]: How to save plot profile data in a text file?

Tags: plot, macros, imagej

I want to make a simple ImageJ macro that draws a profile plot along a given linescan and saves the results in a .txt file. So far, I have:

```
run("Plot Profile");
saveAs("Text", "/path/to/file/Values.txt");
```

This creates the plot in a new window, but then returns an error, stating that a TextWindow is required. I have the suspicion that the macro tries to save the image itself as text instead of the plot data.

How can I implement a macro that does exactly the same as if I were clicking on the "Save As" button of the profile plot or "List -> Save As" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buttons in the plot window are not recorded by ImageJ's macro recorder. (Since you asked the [same question](http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/Help-needed-Macro-to-save-plot-profile-data-as-text-tp5012614.html) on the ImageJ mailing list, there is a chance that this will change in the future.)

Use the `getProfile()` macro function to get the list of values (as shown in this [example macro](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/macros/GetProfileExample.txt)), or use `Plot.getValues(xpoints, ypoints)` to get the values from the plot window (as shown in the other [example macro](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/macros/examples/PlotGetValuesDemo.txt) on the ImageJ website).

For example:

```bs
run("Clear Results");
profile = getProfile();
for (i=0; i<profile.length; i++)
  setResult("Value", i, profile[i]);
updateResults();
saveAs("Measurements", "/path/to/file/Values.txt");
```